# Use GitHub page as domain

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm using the "github page" to create my personal page, but I'm going to need a hosting service because it will require some queries in the database. How can I use my GitHub Page url as a domain?

Comment: Even though you’re using GitHub, this isn’t a programming-related question and probably belongs on a different site. I don’t know if what you want is possible, though. Unless I misread your question; do you want to use https://drigols.github.io/ to point to somewhere hosted elsewhere, or do you want some custom domain to point to GitHub? I think you want the first one, but if it’s the second you just need to do [this](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub pages is not really designed for this kind of function. It's there to be a static page, where all content on the page is 'hardcoded' (meaning no dynamically generated data). What you're asking falls along the lines of a web application.

But if you're looking to be a maverick, there *might* be some options out there for you.

I personally haven't done something like this, but found a couple DB services you might want to check out.

- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) by Google
- [RdbHost](https://www.rdbhost.com/)

The above recommendations may be useful if you're expecting data entry from visitors to your page. But if your data is static as well...you might be better off using s JSON file or some alternative where the data can live right in your repo.